# ansible copy in different host

Tags: ansible

I write a simple playbook to copy some configuration files on a certain machine. 
I need to copy this file in a different host too for backup. Is possible to declare different host in the same playbook?
I need this cause my "backup host" can be different and I retrieve it from the hostname I use.
I tried both copy and raw module and nothing seems to work

here the example of playbook

```
  - name: find file
     find:
       file_type: directory
       paths: /prd/viv/dat/repository/
       patterns: "{{inventory_hostname}}"
       recurse: yes
     register: find
     delegate_to: localhost


   - name: Copy MASTER
     raw:  echo  xmonit$(echo {{find.files[0].path}} | cut -d "/" -f7 )
     delegate_to: localhost
     register: xmonit


   - debug:
       msg: "{{xmonit.stdout}}"


   - name: Copy MASTER raw
     raw:  sshpass -p "mypass" scp {{find.files[0].path}}/master.cfg  myuser@{{xmonit.stdout}}:/prd
     delegate_to: localhost


     #- name: Copy MASTER
       #copy:
         #src: "{{find.files[0].path}}/master.cfg"
         #dest: /prd/cnf/dat/{{inventory_hostname}}/
```

edit: if I use the copy module the destination remains that of the main host while the goal is to copy to a third host.
I need to declare a different host for this single task

```
- name: Copy MASTER
  copy:
    src: "{{find.files[0].path}}/master.cfg"
    dest: /prd/cnf/dat/{{inventory_hostname}}/
```

Comment: 1) Never use raw unless for e.g. installing python on a target to later manage it with "normal" ansible modules 2) `nothing seems to work` is not an accurate description of your current problems. 3) What is wrong exactly with the `copy` module which seems the perfect candidate for this job ? - Please update your question with more precise info

Comment: I can use the modules on the third host but not on the machine declared by the inventory because they have an S.O. outdated which does not support an adequate python version
i edited for better understanding

Comment: You are copying from `localhost` to `some_other_host`. If `some_other_host` is not be the current host in play, simply `delegate_to: some_other_host`.

Comment: acting like that i copy from host1 to "backup host". I'm trying to copy from localhost to "backup host"

Comment: Your latest assertion is wrong. [`copy` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html) copies files from localhost (i.e. ansible controller) to the remote target (i.e. current host in play). If you `delegate_to`, it copies from localhost to the delegated target

Comment: you're right the error was in how the variable was called by changing xmonit.stdout in xmonit.stdout_lines[0] everything worked
thank you so much for the help a trivial mistake has turned into a nightmare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Zeitounator told me in the comments copy module are the best way to act.
like this it work for me

```
    - name: Copy MASTER
      copy:
        src: "{{find.files[0].path}}/master.cfg"
        dest: /prd/cnf/dat/{{inventory_hostname}}/
      delegate_to: xmonit.stdout_lines[0]
```